# localrc settings for openstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

Can anyone please tell the exact configuration for localrc file to do a single node installation of openstack. I have referred many sites and have also tried installation once but somehow it was unsuccessful. I tried using the following configuration:-

```
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcp
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service quantum
```

Is it correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That does not seem wrong, but incomplete.  No sure if you're still looking for an answer, but here's what I use for my single-node devstack (plus Quantum) env:

```
ADMIN_PASSWORD=your_pass
MYSQL_PASSWORD=your_pass
RABBIT_PASSWORD=your_pass
SERVICE_PASSWORD=your_pass
SERVICE_TOKEN=your_pass
HOST_IP=x.x.x.x

DEST=/opt/stack  #installation folder
LOGFILE=stack.sh.log

RECLONE=yes

FLAT_INTERFACE=br100

VOLUME_BACKING_FILE_SIZE=5120M

ENABLED_SERVICES+=,swift 
SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e71ab5c2000f6

disable_service n-net   #This disables Nova network, so it's possible to use Quantum services below:
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcp
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service quantum
enable_service tempest  #Optional, to enable tempest configuration as part of devstack

KEYSTONE_CATALOG_BACKEND=sql

API_RATE_LIMIT=False  #If you're interested in using tempest
```

Basically used this http://devstack.org/localrc.html, which will also elaborate a bit more on the other settings.
Did you get any specific output that you can update here?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this link, 
but I think put multihost=False , if you are not running several nodes.

http://networkstatic.net/openstack-folsom-quantum-devstack-installation-tutorial/